# Execute system command with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, system

I have to build a node.js function, that takes a program, arguments and a string representing stdin. It has to return stdout, stderr (as string), as well as the programs exit code and the function should be synchronous.

`(program, arguments, stdin_string) => [stdout_string, stderr_string, exit_code]`

PS: I already checked the docs, but haven't found something like this... it would be nice if the solution would work without the need of extra modules (only the ones who are in the node.js platform from installation)

Comment: [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: I sayd that I already checked the docs...

Comment: It would be nice to get an implementation of the function I required in the question, 'cause I  do not know how to implement it

Comment: You can't expect functions to exist for every particular use case that you may have, it will require _some_ effort on your part on implementing something. The examples shown for [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) almost implement exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you give me the implementation of that function, which I can not implement, 'cause I dont know how to do so....

Comment: Can you show the code you already have and tell us the specific problem(s)?